# Selenium2Library - Selects window but fails

Tags: selenium2library

I have an issue trying to select a window using Select Window command. There is no title for the window when I select it but when I try

Select Window    title=Mozilla Firefox

it selects the window but then returns ValueError and fails. The window is a Popup window after selecting a button on another page. I have tried using url and also javascript but still returns the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Kyle

Comment: is it a pop up ? or a html modal or a lay over ? can you share some more information.

Comment: It is a pop up window that opens when the button is used with the Click Button command.

Comment: just to re-confirm a javascript pop up ? and can you share some code.

Comment: I thought so when I view source the command for that particular window is xyz.js. In the window though it is a .html url

Comment: The error is ValueError: Unable to locate window with title 'Mozilla Firefox' as well if that might help...

Comment: can you try this, get the exact length of the title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117425/discussion-between-shek-and-user2929005).